# Transforming functions of type `a -> b` into those of type `String -> String` in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

My intention is simple. I want to wrap functions of type `a -> b` into `String -> String` (so that a bunch of heterogeneous functions can be put in a list). So I write:

```
wrap :: (Read a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> (String -> String)
wrap f = \s -> show $ f (read s :: a)
```

However, `ghc` complaints:

```
Could not deduce (Read a1) arising from a use of `read'
from the context (Read a, Show b)
  bound by the type signature for
             wrap :: (Read a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> String -> String
```

I want to know why my piece of code won't work and what kind of hacks is needed to achieve my goal?

Thanks.

Comment: Putting a bunch of heterogeneous functions in a list is not good haskell, and wrapping them all up in String transformation is definitely bad haskell.  What are you trying to do in a larger sense?

Comment: This is a mistake. Don't do this. You're throwing away Haskell's powerful type system, and all the great compile-time checking that goes with it. A mechanic who tells you your car is fine and then it breaks down on the freeway isn't as much use as a mechanic who tells you to spend $50 fixing something (now, while it's in the garage) that's going to cause you to break down (later, after it's caused more damage, there's a call-out fee and the guy fixing it doesn't have the part he needs with him). Static typing is the good mechanic, dynamic typing is the one who says it's fine.

Comment: @NovaDenizen I'm definitely into static typing. Recently I've been writing a simple server. `a -> IO b` stands for a implemented service. One component is to convert `[(String, a -> IO b)]` to `Map String (a -> IO b)`. But the type system doesn't allow that. I do have more intricate design of types in my mind to enforce type safety (so that the client has to feed an input of type `a` to the service of type `a -> IO b` otherwise the whole program won't type check). But the catch is the server may not be serving clients written in Haskell at all. So my mechanism doesn't work in that case.

Comment: @AndrewC Also I'm curious if there's a way to enforce type-safety between Haskell and other statically-typed FP languages (say, OCaml)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code won't work because Haskell doesn't re-use or scope type variables; the `a` in `wrap :: (Read a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> (String -> String)` is a completely different `a` from the one in `read s :: a` (and they're both universally quantified).  This is the source of the `a1` in the error message; GHC is alpha-converting the program to

```
wrap :: (Read a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> (String -> String)
wrap f = \s -> show $ f (read s :: a1)
```

However, `f`'s argument type is fixed inside `wrap`, so simply removing the type annotation works fine. Your function becomes

```
wrap :: (Read a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> (String -> String)
wrap f = \s -> show $ f (read s)
  -- Or wrap f = show . f . read
```

And you can use it:

```
ghci> map ($ "42") [wrap (+ (7 :: Integer)), wrap (* (2.0 :: Double))]
["49","84.0"]
```

Note that this means that `read s` has a type you can't write down.  In Haskell 2010 (or 98), the only way to get around this is to use a function like [`asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aasTypeOf); `asTypeOf` is just `const`, but thanks to its type signature, it constrains its first, returned, argument to be of the same type as its second.  Then, of course, you'd have to conjure up a variable of type `a`.  The following would work for that:

```
wrap :: (Read a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> (String -> String)
wrap f = \s -> show $ f (read s `asTypeOf` fInput)
  where fInput = undefined
        fOutput = f fInput -- I still can't give this a type signature
```

In GHC, to avoid this, you can turn on [the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables); with that on, if you explicitly qualify all your type variables with a `forall`, they'll be scoped just like value-level names.  Then your code would become

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
wrap :: forall a b. (Read a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> (String -> String)
wrap f = \s -> show $ f (read s :: a)
```

But remember, you don't need any type annotations at all for this simple example.

Answer (score 10):

To specify the type of `read s` explicitly, you'll need something like `ScopedTypeVariables`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
...
wrap :: forall a b. (Read a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> (String -> String)
wrap f = \s -> show $ f (read s :: a)
```

Since otherwise the `:: a` annotation inside the function refers to a different type from the `a` in the type signature (it implicitly means `:: forall a. a`). But note that you can also just drop the type annotation entirely:

```
wrap :: (Read a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> (String -> String)
wrap f = \s -> show $ f (read s)
```

Since the type of `read s` can be inferred. That also lets you simplify the body to

```
wrap f = show . f . read
```